# How to generate all possible binary strings from a clue effectively?

Tags: python-3.x

I can get a clue in the form of a list (e.g. [1,3,1]) and the length of the string (e.g. 8) and I generate all possible strings given the clue. That is:

- 01011101
- 10111010
- 10111001
- 10011101

Having three groups of 1s separated by one or more 0s of length given by the clue (in that order).

The clue specifies lengths of groups of 1s separated by at least one 0. The order of these groups must follow the order in the clue list.

My approach would be to use recursion, where each call tries to insert a specific group of 1s in the string (in the order of the clue list). It uses a for-loop to place it in all possible indices of the string and recursively calls itself for each of these placements with a `clue = clue[1:]` and `size = size - clue[0]`.

How can I do that effectively in Python?

Comment: Can you please clarify what the "clue in the form of a list" even means? Does ``[1,3,1]`` mean one group of 1 1, one group of 3 1s, one group of 1 1? Are these in order? Do you have any approach to solving this?

Comment: Yes, all these groups in the specific order separated by at least one 0. I will include my approach in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `combinations_with_replacement` to generate all possible combinations and build your answers that way.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from collections import Counter

def generate_answers(clue, length):
    segs = len(clue) + 1  # segment indices that a zero can be placed
    excess_zeros = length - sum(clue) - (segs - 2)  # number of zeros that can be moved around
    for comb in combinations_with_replacement(range(segs), excess_zeros):
        count = Counter(comb)  # number of zeros to be added to each segment
        for i in range(1, len(clue)):
            count[i] += 1  # add the zeros required to separate the ones
        output = ''
        for i in range(segs):  # build string
            output += '0' * count[i]
            if i < len(clue):
                output += '1' * clue[i]
        print(output)
        
clue = [1, 3, 1]
length = 8

generate_answers(clue, length)
```

Output:

```
'01011101'
'10011101'
'10111001'
'10111010'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it (recursively) without external libraries:

```
def generate_answers(clue, size):
    if len(clue) == 0:
        return [[0 for _ in range(size)]]
    groups = gen_groups(clue)
    min_len = sum(clue) + len(clue) - 1
    free_spaces = size - min_len
    result = recursive_combinations(len(groups) + 1, free_spaces)
    solution = []
    for res in result:
        in_progress = []
        for i in range(len(groups)):
            in_progress += [0 for _ in range(res[i])]
            in_progress += groups[i]
        in_progress += [0 for _ in range(res[-1])]
        solution.append(in_progress)
    return solution

def gen_groups(clue):
    result = []
    for elem in clue:
        in_progress = []
        for i in range(elem):
            in_progress.append(1)
        in_progress.append(0)
        result.append(in_progress)   
    if len(result) > 0:
        result[-1].pop()    
    return result   

def recursive_combinations(fields, zeroes):
    if fields <= 0 or zeroes< 0:
        return []    
    if fields == 1:
        return [[zeroes]]   
    solution = [] 
    for i in range(zeroes+ 1):
        result = recursive_combinations(fields - 1, zeroes- i)
        solution += [[i] + res for res in result]
    return solution
```